# Display JSON objects list in a Grid with react-virtualized

Tags: json, reactjs, datatable, react-virtualized

How to display a List of objects with react-virtualized, in a Grid.

In the documentation, it shows how to iterate over `cellRenderer` function, but I'd like to iterate over JSON objects.

```
cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
   return (
     <div
       key={key}
       style={style}>
       {this.state.list[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
     </div>)
}

// in render()

<Grid
      cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
      columnCount={list[0].length}
      columnWidth={100}
      height={200}
      rowCount={list.length}
      rowHeight={30}
      width={1000}
/>
```

How to adapt this function to display JSON Objects instead of a list of strings?

Using examples from react-virtualized I was able to display arrays of arrays of Strings, I've already a Table that displays Data objects and I wanted it scrollable without performance loss. So to me react-virtualized was the best known option.

But is there another way to display custom content (e.g : JSON objects through react-virtualized library)?

I've been lazy on my proposed solution, which was to use react-virtualized scroll feature to display my Data-table as one cell column without having to redefine it.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Please update the question to provide more information or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to enjoy the benefits of the scrollable Grid without rewriting the whole rendering design would be to render inside cellRenderer the DataTable generated from another method :

```
cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  const {
    myWideDataTable
  } = this.state

  return (
    <div
      {myWideDataTable}
    </div>)
}

// in render()

<Grid
  cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
  columnCount={1}
  columnWidth={1000}
  height={1000}
  rowCount={1}
  rowHeight={30}
  width={1000}
/>
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: That's one solution that'll not work if you want to edit the content in the scrollzone